# How to use Vue Router programatically with native events?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have been trying to use native events with Vue router using this.$router.push and I keep producing the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

found in

---> <section>
```

I can't seem to figure out why and I have to use multiple solutions, all of which produce the above error. Some of them redirect to the page directly before triggering the event.

Things that I have tried:

1.

```
//in JSX
<section nativeOnClick={this.navigationPage('login')}></section>

// in methods I have the following:
methods: {
  navigationPage: function (page) {
    this.$router.push(page)
  }
}
```

2.

```
//in JSX
<section nativeOnClick={this.$router.push('login')}></section>
```

One solution that works is the following:

```
//in JSX
<section nativeOnClick={this.navigateToLogin}></section>

// in methods I have the following:
methods: {
  navigateToLogin: function () {
    this.$router.push(page)
  }
}
```

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong in 1 and 2. The solution that works is fine but that requires me to create a method for every navigation. I personally like 2!!

Any help is appreciated

***NEW***
Below is the full component definition:

```
//navbar.js

import styles from './index.styl'
import logo from 'Src/assets/logo.svg'
import menu from 'Src/assets/menu.svg'

export default {
  name: 'NavBar',
  methods: {
    navigationPage: function (page) {
      this.$router.push(page)
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    return (
      <ui-nav class={styles.nav}>
        <ui-section class={styles.navLogo} nativeOnClick={ this.navigationPage('hello') }>
          <ui-image source={logo} />
        </ui-section>
        <ui-spacer />
        <ui-section class={styles.navMenu}>
          <ui-image source={menu} />
        </ui-section>
      </ui-nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Note: This style also automatically navigates to `/hello` (i.e. before click event). I do not know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is one solution that works, but I can't understand why it works though!

working solution:

```
<section nativeOnClick={ () => this.$router.push('hello') }></section>
```

The thing that is confusing is why passing arguments without the handler produces the error by when wrapping with a function it does not.
i.e

```
<section nativeOnClick={ this.$router.push('hello') }></section> // GIVES error
```

Comment: I just found out the reason. The working solution is the only way to do this since this is in the context of JSX and on* events needs a callback in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `this` reserved word from your jsx native invocation?, for example:

```
<section nativeOnClick={ navigationPage('login') }></section>
```

If you can you post the whole script of your single file component (or whatever you are editing) would be helpful for me to be in context.

Comment: removing this did not work. This produced an error saying navigationPage is not defined.

Comment: I just edited the question to ad the component definition.

Comment: I think the problem is the nativeOnClick, try using @click='this.navigationPage("login")' instead of nativeOnClick={ navigationPage('login') }

Comment: I can't use @click since this is in JSX but using both native and non-native (onClick and nativeOnClick) produces the same error.